# node with mongodb : iterate on distinct result without loading everything into memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am discovering node and mongo at the same time and I had one question :

I have a City collection :

```
{
  _id : mongoid
  countryId : string
  name : string
}
```

Each city is rattached to one country, and multiple cities can be rattached to the same country. For external reason, this data got corrupted, and some cities have a name equal to null instead of having a valid value (like Paris or London). I need to delete all cities (with a valid name or a null name) for a country where at least one city is having a name equal to null.

For example:

1. if Country France has only 2 cities (one with name Paris and one with name Marseille), nothing has to be deleted
2. if Country France has only 2 cities (one with name Paris and one with a name null), both cities have to be deleted
3. if Country France has only 2 cities (both with null names), both cities have to be deleted

I have managed to do that with the following code (node-mongodb-native 3.1 and node 12.16.1):

```
const invalidCountryIds = await db.collection('City').distinct('countryId',
{
  name:null
}

console.log(invalidCountryIds.length)

invalidCountryIds.forEach(async countryId => {
    await db.collection('City').deleteMany({
        countryId:countryId
    })
```

I have however 2 questions, this **City** collection could be possibly very big (more than 10k records) so I wanted to be sure that I was doing that in the most performant way :

1. when I am calling the `.length`, am I loading the whole collection of `invalidCountryIds` into memory
2. is this foreach the best way to iterate on this collection of `invalidCountryIds`, I am seeing in documentation that I can also use the `.next` method available from the cursor object, is there any difference between iterating with this `foreach` and the `next cursor`, are both loading into memory only the current element of the collection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You have already loaded the whole result of `invalidCountryIds` when you query it with `await db.collection('City').distinct('countryId', { name: null })`
2. Using `cursor`, you will load the result to the memory row by row (by default) and you can handle each row. So using `cursor` will be more memory efficient (not necessarily faster). With queries other than `distinct` you can also specify the batchSize, the number of documents you will fetch the result from the database each batch.

Comment: is there a way to avoid loading eveything in memory and just iterate and only load the current record at each step?

Comment: You can use `cursor` as mentioned in the answer 2.

Comment: But you just said that "using the cursor,you will load the result to the memory", or maybe I didnt understand well, by result, you mean a single element, not the whole collection?

Comment: Sorry, I might have been ambiguous, the cursor will fetch the result row by row (by default). I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am trying to use the cursor to iterate but the following is not working  : `db.collection('City').distinct('countryId', { name: null }).forEach(//my work)` as the distinct return a promise

Comment: You have to do `db.collection('City').distinct('countryId', { name: null }).cursor().eachAsync()`. See multiple ways to use cursor here: https://thecodebarbarian.com/cursors-in-mongoose-45

Comment: the compiler is telling me that the cursor method is not available, I am using node-mongodb-native and not mongoose fyi, this could explain why I cant use your solution maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you used mongoose. From what I've read, you can't use distinct with cursor. So I think it won't work with mongoose as well.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, instead of the distinct, I will use an aggregate and group by CountryId, this will returns me a cursor